# Finding Subgame-Perfect Nash Equilibrium in Games of Imperfect Information

Tags: game-theory

How to proceed in the following finite game of imperfect information to solve for subgame perfect Nash equilibrium? The only subgame is the game itself. And by converting the extensive form into a normal form game to arrive at the pure strategy nash equilibrium I am getting (C,q) which somehow doesn't seem to be correct.

[image]

Comment: $(C, q)$ is the only pure-strategy subgame perfect equilibrium of this game.

Comment: Why do you think your answer is not correct?